# Shortcut / alias to refer to python class for internal methods

Tags: python

Consider a `class` *StateMgrListener* with a class level variable `rcvCntr`:

```
class StateMgrListener(BaseListener):
  rcvCntr = 0

  def handler(self,msg):
    StateMgrListener.rcvCntr += 1
```

Rather than that repetitive use of the entire class name I would prefer to reference that class variable in a manner similar to:

```
    s.rcvCntr += 1
```

But the following does *not* work:

```
class StateMgrListener(BaseListener):
  s = StateMgrListener  # "NameError: name 'StateMgrListener' is not defined"
  rcvCntr = 0
```

Is there any means to achieve this?

Comment: Conventionally the first argument to a method is always called `self`. You're confusing things by using the same variable as your shortcut.

Comment: @Barmar  corrected that for the purposes of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the class isn't defined until after the class definition has been executed.

You can assign `StateMgrListener.s` after creating the class:

```
class StateMgrListener(BaseListener):
    def handler(self, msg):
        s.revCntr += 1

StateMgrListener.s = StateMgrListener
```

Another option is to set it in the `__init__` method.

```
class StateMgrListener(BaseListener):
    def __init__(self):
        StateMgrListener.s = StateMgrListener
        ...

    def handler(self, msg):
        s.revCntr += 1
```

Comment: I did think of that - the risk being if any method were invoked internally as part of class initialization that refers to `s`

Comment: True. Another option is to set it in the `__init__` method.

Comment: oh! so in `__init__` it will be available - then that's likely what I am looking for!

Comment: .. except that I'm subclassing `tornado.RequestWebHandler` - which disallows an `__init()__` method. Now _that_ annoyance is a separate discussion altogether..

Comment: Given your experience I am going to be optimistic that your solution with `__init()__` works and award.

Comment: My experience? I've never written a line of Python code except when answering SO questions.

Comment: That's amusing. Well i'm going to use this approach  soon enough in any case

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you *don't* refer to the class by name. You access the attribute via the instance:

```
def handler(self, msg):
    type(self).rcvCntr += 1
```

True, this means that if a subclass of `StateMgrListener` defines its own class attribute named `rcvCntr`, that's the attribute that gets incremented, not `StateMgrListener.rcvCntr`. However, that's usually what you would *want*.

Another option would be to disallow direct access to *class* variables from instance methods, and go through a class method instead.

```
@classmethod
def incr_counter(cls):
    cls.rcvCntr += 1

def handler(self, msg):
    self.incr_counter()
```

This assumes that `hander` uses `self` for something aside from access to `incr_counter`; if it doesn't, then `handler` itself is a candidate to be a class method.

Comment: Agreed about _wanting_ the subclass attribute to be accessed.  This is still rather verbose but well i guess that's what we have. Thx

Comment: It's not like you have to type this a lot. Optimize for reading, not writing. Also, have you considered simply using shorter class names?

Comment: We all have our "things".  I can not stand the `self.someMethod` and `self.someAttribute` and use `s.someMethod` instead.  My team is all aboard about ditching PEP.  I'm likely to use the suggestion to put into `__init__` and will use `c` to indicate the class itself.  I find it more readable actually.